# ng-show is not working with boolean values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to bind few divs with service values"

```
<body ng-controller="PageConfigurationController">
<label>{{TopLeftPage}}</label><label>{{TopRightPage}}</label>
<label>{{ButtomRightPage}}</label><label>{{ButtomLeftPage}}</label>
<div ng-show="{{TopLeftPage}}"><h1>Div1 </h1></div>
<div ng-show="{{TopRightPage}}"><h1>Div2 </h1></div>
<div ng-show="{{ButtomRightPage}}"><h1>Div3 </h1></div>
<div ng-show="{{ButtomLeftPage}}"><h1>Div4 </h1></div>
```

The labels are showing the booleans values fine, but by default all the divs are hidded, no matter if it is true or false.

Comment: ng-show is already angular binded no need of {{}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <div ng-show="TopLeftPage"><h1>Div1 </h1></div>
  <div ng-show="TopRightPage"><h1>Div2 </h1></div>
  <div ng-show="ButtomRightPage"><h1>Div3 </h1></div>
  <div ng-show="ButtomLeftPage"><h1>Div4 </h1></div>
```

Remove curly braces from your ng-show  and in js

```
  $scope.TopLeftPage=true;
  $scope.TopRightPage=true;
  $scope.ButtomRightPage=true;
  $scope.ButtomLeftPage=true;
```

// true for show and false for hide

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use expression in ng-show

```
<div ng-show="TopLeftPage"><h1>Div1 </h1></div>
<div ng-show="TopRightPage"><h1>Div2 </h1></div>
<div ng-show="ButtomRightPage"><h1>Div3 </h1></div>
<div ng-show="ButtomLeftPage"><h1>Div4 </h1></div>
```

And be sure that the value of expression should be true or false boolean not string